# Definitive method to exclude page sections from main search engines

Tags: search, seo, search-engine

I have quite a few constant parts of pages I'd like to exclude from displaying in search results to prevent obscuring of the unique content on each respective page.

I read that class="nocontent" will perform this action for Google. But what about the other main search engines like Yahoo and Bing? Is there a globally accepted solution for this, or is there an additional step to get them to do the same?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: `nocontent` doesn't work for Google Search. It's only for use with Google *Custom* Search.

Comment: I see.. How about this then. Is there a way to set in which order search engines crawl a page? Like for example. Say I had a div or section on the page for the first content visible in the HTML document which was a navigational sidebar. While the actual unique content was a div/section after it. Is there a way to tell search engines I want them to read one of those divs before the others?

Comment: Well, that is the point about the semantic use of HTML, isn't it? By using the right elements (e.g. `nav` for your navigation) you did your job by telling user-agents *what* your content is. Now those user-agents (e.g. search engine bots) *can* make use of it (if they want to), e.g. by lowering the keyword score for navigation etc. —— Also, pages are parsed from top to bottom, and some search engines *might* consider content at the top to be more imporant. If you feel that this is the case/important, you'd have to place the "secondary" content after the primary/main content in the HTML.

Comment: Ah, I honestly had no idea those tags were recognized by search engines for that purpose. I suppose that makes a lot more sense in hindsight than needlessly adding them instead of a div. Thank you.

Comment: Well, we can never know for sure *a)* which search engines do recognize *b)* which elements and *c)* how they handle them. Some may even do nothing about semantic elements. But if they want to get better than their competitors, they'd have to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

*Google* doesn't offer such a feature for the general search. The class [`nocontent`](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364585) is only for Google Custom Search. The comments [`googleon`/`googleoff`](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing#pagepart) are only for Google Search Appliance.

*Yahoo!* [introduced](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2007/05/02/introducing-robots-nocontent-for-page-sections/) the class `robots-nocontent` in 2007. *Google* [doesn't support](https://twitter.com/mattcutts/statuses/2499654256) it.

There is a [microformats draft](http://microformats.org/wiki/robots-exclusion), but it has probably no support.

---

Despite that, there are some "hacks" that could accomplish what you need, but I wouldn't count on or use them. For example: inserting content with JS, or embedding content in `iframe` (and blocking the source URL in `robots.txt`).